# Using Fake Sendmail with PHP

Tags: windows, php, sendmail

When attempting to send from PHP via sendmail it just hangs.
Using IIS

sendmail.ini is setup correctly because from command line I can send a test email via the following

```
sendmail -t < %temp%\temp.mail
```

now the PHP version is old 5.2.5.5. So I think there is some issue with parsing the php.ini file maybe?

Below tells me it can't launch Sendmail

```
sendmail_path = "C:\Inetpub\Sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
```

Now if I change it to the following

```
sendmail_path = "\"C:\Inetpub\Sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t
```

It acts like its running but just hangs there until the timeout is reached.

What is the magic trick here?

Comment: Perhaps add the -i flag?

Comment: Open xammp/wamp as administrator should be working

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. But I answer it anyway:

In my php.ini file I do not use double quotes around the path to the sendmail.exe file. Here is how this line looks like in my php.ini :

```
sendmail_path = C:/usr/fakesendmail/sendmail.exe -t -i
```

Of course, I also have a line like this in php.ini :

```
sendmail_from = my@emailaddress.com
```

Where my@emailaddress.com is my real valid email address.

I hope this helps someone!